# where should I put crossdomain.xml in my grails app

Tags: apache-flex, grails

Hi Could anyone tell me where should I put the crossdomain.xml to my grails app?
I need to use webservices from external domains in my flex client app.
I put it into my web-app folder but it seems not working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some scenarios in past applications where I needed to dynamically generate my crossdomain.xml file. Here's what I did.

Within your UrlMapping.groovy add the following

```
"/crossdomain"(view:"/crossdomain")
```

Then create a crossdomain.gsp file within your views root

```
<%@ page contentType="text/xml;charset=UTF-8" %>
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

You can test it out by pointing your browser to: http://hostname:port/contextPath/crossdomain.xml

Answer (score 1):

The server you are connecting to (if it is not the same as the server from which the SWF originated from) must have the crossdomain.xml file.  If that server doesn't have one and you can't put one there, then you must proxy the server (through mod_proxy or BlazeDS's proxy server).

Answer (score 1):

You can also just drop the crossdomain.xml in the web-app directory.